# Requirements.txt file failing with a Git repo source

Tags: python, git, pip, python-3.7

I have this requirements file:

```
requests==2.24.0
-e git+ssh://git@omyurl/path/to/mygit.git#egg=mymodule
```

Ad when I `pip install -r requirements.txt -t some/folder`, I get:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /../.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/../src/mymodule/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/../src/mymodule/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --home=/private/var/folders/14/xyz/T/pip-target-9ag4c8zg
         cwd: /../src/mymodule/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
    
    error: option --home not recognized
```

When I go the long route and bring the repo down and `pip install -e . -t some/folder`, I get the same error. But when I `pip install . -t some/folder`, no errors. Any idea how to make this work with requirements.txt?

Comment: Show us the full output and not just one line.

Comment: Expanded the error, but found a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be anything more than a python bug . A possible solution to the problem would be removing the `-t` from your `pip install -r requirements.txt -t some/folder` .

The problem has occurred before and a little search on the internet would take you [here](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/240).

Edit: The answer to this was removing `-e` from requirements.txt.

Comment: Thanks, a comment down that thread you linked helped me resolve it: "please try to remove the -e before your requirements". Verified and it works.